# Merging rows into one with same column cells and keep data from all into the merged row using python script

Tags: python, csv, merge, rows

I need to merge more rows into one but in the way i can keep all data in all columns into the merged row in my .csv file. The rows which i need to merge are one who have same email cells. The first table in the picture is how i have now and the second how should be.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgpuh.png)

I need to do this with Python script. Can anyone help me?

Thank you Igor

Comment: Did you already try something? Please post relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Also post your input and expected output here too, not as linked images.

Comment: This is not a very clear question. First of all, you don't show what you have tried so far. Next it is not clear, what should happen for row merges, when there is conflicting information and stuff like that. So please try to do it yourself and come back with specific questions for difficulties you face.

Comment: Also post or tag whether you are using pandas

Comment: I don't have any code i just tried some examples posted here but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my idea: start at row 1, take the email and store it in a list.

Now compare each entry of the the hole email column with the email from row 1. If its equal then find out which fields in your row are empty and if the found entry has one of these filled out.

Write the concatenated row down and go on with the second row/email.

Dont forget to check if the new email has already checked (see if there is a entry in the list from start) and go on.

A bit of work but very low level, im pretty sure there is a smarter solution, but this should work too.

Comment: This is good explained but how to code it with Python is the question?
I succeed just to read the first email in the row but so on i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Maybe you should start with a python tutorial because this is really basic stuff, or try to google the 'keywords' in my answer like 'python list' and how to use it. You will learn a lot more if you figure it out on your own than let other program it for you